# Add prefix to twig trans filter

Tags: symfony, dns, twig, translation, yaml

I have a messages.de.yml that looks like

```
...
profile:
    ...  
    availability:
        ...
        4_week: Vier mal pro Woche
        ...
...
```

(The ... are not important for this example)

I have a user class that has a field called availability. I want to display this field in the user's profile and to translate it. Let's assume the value of user.availability is "4_week"

This code is working:

```
{{ ("profile.availability." ~ user.availability)|trans }}
```

But is this really the recommended way? I tried using profile.availability / messages.profile.availability as domain:

```
{{ user.availability|trans({}, "profile.availability") }}
```

But the output is just 4_week and not "Vier mal pro Woche" as expected.

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the recommended way.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I find this not very beautiful but if it's recommended it's OK I think :)